# Visual Studio: Change Build Configuration --> Auto Change Startup Project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm wondering if anyone has figured out a way to do this.  Here is the scenario....I have a build configuration called "UnitTest".  When I run my unit tests I need to change the startup project.  I often forget to do that second step.  My build is large and time consuming.  So, when I forget to change the startup project it wastes time.  I wonder if there is a way to automatically change the startup project when I change my build configuration?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

We were having the same issue.

We have a huge solution with over 100 projects. For CI purposes we had to build everything which became a nightmare.

I found this which seems to be the solution. Still testing but so far it looks exactly what you need.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TepperAmir.StartupProjects